# String fuzzy-matching From R to Python

Tags: python, r

I am trying to use string fuzzy-matching with both R and Python.
I am actually using two packages:

1. `stringdist` from R
2. `fuzzywuzzy` from Python

When I try `amatch("PARI", c("HELLO", "WORLD"), maxDist = 2)` on R, I get `NA` as a result, which is intuitive.
But when I try the same thing with Python :  `process.extract("PARI", ["HELLO", "WORLD"], limit = 2)`, I get `[('world', 22), ('HELLO', 0)]`

Could anyone tell me why I have a 22 as a ratio matching between "PARI" and "WORLD" ?
How could I get the same result as in R ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is `limit = 2` specifically says you want 2 results regardless of the score, whereas in R you are specifying that you only want a result if the strings are very close to one another. The score here is a measure from 0 to 100 of how similar the words are. You can see `PARI` and `world` both have `R` as their third letter, which is why you get a non-zero score, but it still isn't a very good one.

Comment: I did remove limit from Python's code, still I have the same result as before !

Comment: @Hakimachraf the default limit is 5. However, if you set the `limit` to zero, you will not get any results even if you have a perfect match. You should filter your results based on score rather than limiting how many appear.

Comment: So what is the equivalent score for maxDist = 2 in Python ?